# signInWithRedirect() function in Firebase authentication not working In ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, firebase, authentication, redirect, firebase-authentication

## The Issue

I've been attempting to use Firebase in my React application, however, the function, `signInWithRedirect(auth, provider)` doesn't work. `signInWithPopup()` works as intended, but not the redirect one.

## What I've tried

I know my Firebase config is fine because `signInWithPopup()` works perfectly.
I've double checked that it's not working by running:

```
const check = () => {
  console.log(auth?.currentUser?.displayName);

  getRedirectResult(auth).then((result) => {
    console.log(result);
  });
};
```

Both logging `auth.currentUser.displayname` and the redirect result return with null or undefined, which means that the login was a failure.

Apart from the techincal side, I have also went into Google Cloud console and changed the application status to testing rather than production, and I double checked that the 'localhost' domain was whitelisted. Both haven't seemed to bring a solution.

## The code

#### Authy.js (the Firebase utility file)

```
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import {
  getAuth,
  getRedirectResult,
  signInWithPopup,
  signInWithRedirect,
  signOut,
} from "firebase/auth";
import { GoogleAuthProvider } from "firebase/auth";

// Your web app's Firebase configuration
const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "<These are filled out by me obviously>",
  authDomain: "<These are filled out by me obviously>",
  projectId: "<These are filled out by me obviously>",
  storageBucket: "<These are filled out by me obviously>",
  messagingSenderId: "<These are filled out by me obviously>",
  appId: "<These are filled out by me obviously>",
};

// Initialize Firebase
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
// Initialize Firebase Authentication and get a reference to the service
const auth = getAuth(app);

const provider = new GoogleAuthProvider();

export const signInWithGoogle = async () => {
  await signInWithRedirect(auth, provider);
};

export const check = () => {
  console.log(auth?.currentUser?.displayName);

  getRedirectResult(auth).then((result) => {
    console.log(result);
  });
};

export const signMeOut = () => {
  signOut(auth);
};
```

#### App.jsx

```
import { signInWithGoogle, signMeOut, check } from "./authy";

function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={signInWithGoogle}>Sign In</button>
      <br />
      <button onClick={signMeOut}>Sign out</button>
      <br />
      <button onClick={check}>log</button>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

## What happens with the code above

When I press the sign in button, it directs me to the Google sign in webpage, which is completely blank. The URL seems correct. This is the one it redirects me to:

[https://react-commerce-ff44c.firebaseapp.com/__/auth/handler?apiKey={My](https://react-commerce-ff44c.firebaseapp.com/__/auth/handler?apiKey=%7BMy) api key goes here}&appName=%5BDEFAULT%5D&authType=signInViaRedirect&redirectUrl=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2F&v=9.21.0&providerId=google.com&scopes=profile

After 2-3 seconds on a this completely blank, white page, it redirects me back to localhost. I thought that maybe I was already signed in and that there was no need for Google to show me a sign in page if I was already logged in, but I wasn't. Again my `check()` function in `Authy.js` proves it.

## What I expect to happen

I expect it to redirect me to a Google sign in / log in page, where, after registration It redirects me back to my site.

Comment: I would suggest having a look at what is going on in: https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials/consent/edit?project=your_project. Check whether the app status is "Production"or "Testing". If it is production the localhost origin will likely be blocked. And then also make sure the domain you are using is whitelisted.

Comment: @Stf_F I unfortunately have done these as well and also tested them. I'll make sure to edit the original question to include the things that you said I should do. In the meantime, would you have any other suggestions?

Comment: What does your console tell you? Do you see any errors/warnings or network requests being blocked etc.?